# Number of real roots of polynomial Rolle

Tags: polynomials

How can I find the number of real roots for: $$x^4-14x^2-24x+10=0$$ I derived it and got $$4x^3-28x-24=(x+1)(x^2-x-6)=0$$ found $x=0$ ,$x=3$ and $x=-2$. I tried finding the number of signs change with Rolle and found 5 but its wrong the answer should be 2.

Comment: Use double derivative test.

Comment: yes I meant -1 was in a rush,would double derivative test work?heard about it but don't know how to apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You took the derivative of the given polynomial $p$ and found $(x+1)(x-3)(x+2)=0$.  Therefore, the roots of the derivative are at $x=-1$, $x=-2$, and $x=3$.  These are possible extreme points of $p$.  Substituting them into $p$, we get

\begin{align*}
p(-2)&=16-56+48+10=18>0\\
p(-1)&=1-14+24+10=21>0\\
p(3)&=81-126-72+10=-106<0.
\end{align*}
Hence, there is no root between $-2$ and $-1$.  On the other hand, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a root between $-1$ and $3$.  Now, we need to find roots outside the interval $[-2,3]$.  Since this is an even polynomial, the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\pm\infty}p(x)=+\infty$, so there is no root to the left of $-2$ because the function is already positive, but there is a root to the right of $3$ since the polynomial must switch from negative to positive at some point.

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake when I calculated p(-2) I found it was negative